# How to create or is there already spinning dialog in PySide which I can use while my request from server is finished ?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

How to create or is there already spinning dialog which I can use while my request from server is finished ? I have to download file and in that time I have to notify user that some action is executing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt loading indicator widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958644/qt-loading-indicator-widget)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate, even the answers are completely identical.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**
Havn't tried the PyQt version yet but here you go :
https://github.com/ertanguven/desktop-service/blob/master/pds/qprogressindicator.py

Which is based on : https://github.com/mojocorp/QProgressIndicator

**Solution 2:** 
Using QMovie to load a .gif file

```
class ImagePlayer(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, filename, title, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # Load the file into a QMovie
        self.movie = QtGui.QMovie(filename, QByteArray(), self)

        size = self.movie.scaledSize()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, size.width(), size.height())
        self.setWindowTitle(title)

        self.movie_screen = QtGui.QLabel()
        # Make label fit the gif
        self.movie_screen.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.movie_screen.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Create the layout
        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.movie_screen)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

        # Add the QMovie object to the label
        self.movie.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)
        self.movie.setSpeed(100)
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()

def run():
    global my_window
    try:
        my_window.close()
        my_window.deleteLater()
    except: pass
    my_window = ImagePlayer(r'Path/To/loader.gif', "Hello")
    my_window.show()

run()
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/Svenito/4000025)

**Solution 3 (this is not what you want):** A Progress Bar.
[image: QProgressDialog]
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qprogressdialog.html

**Bonus:**
[Loader.gif](http://www.rpgnow.com/shared_images/ajax-loader.gif)